# Nvidia GeForce 210 on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

Last night I installed the Geforce 210 into my HP a6152n Desktop, in attempts to get Starcraft 2 just up and running (Not a HUGE gamer and I don't really need all of the bells and whistles).

The Computer booted fine while using the Nouveau driver by default, so I figured everything was good. I ran Starcraft 2 through PlayonLinux and Wine and the game boots correctly, the loading screen seems fine, until you get into the Battlenet login screen.

None of the text is readable! It's all white blocks, and it seems as if the background doesn't have all of the necessary graphics.

Bare with me, I'm a week new to Ubuntu.

So I start trying all of the "experimental" and proprietary driver included in Additional Drivers and none of them work. They all break Unity and the startup splash screen. The splash screen looks like it's from DOS, and When the computer boots it's resolution is way down, and there's no Dash or top bar for me to do anything.

Any advice is appreciated.

My setup:

- HP a6152n
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600
- 3BG RAM
- Nvidia Geforce 210 (Hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> and try the following in the terminal:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Reboot. If that doesn't do the trick run `ccsm` in the term and re-enable the unity plugin.

If ccsm is not installed run:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

If that doesn't help either I would suggest this:

remove nvidia

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current
```

depending on the driver you have installed. If you want you can run both to make sure.

add the [x-swat ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) THE REPO IS NOT OFFICIAL BUT STABLE

install ppa-purge in case the ppa doesn't work for you

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

add repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

update package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install newer drivers

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Reboot

if it doesn't work out you can revert back with

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```